# Timer is lagging in the UI

Tags: delphi, timer, delphi-xe7

I have a `TTimer` component that is used for stopwatch functionality, and shows data in a `TEdit` as `'h:m:s --- 0.00 dollars'`, as follows:

```
procedure TBillardApp.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  sec:=sec+1;
  if sec >= 60 then
  begin
    sec:=0;
    min:=min+1;
  end;

  if min >= 60 then
  begin
    min:=0;
    hour:=hour+1;
  end;
  BillCounter1:=BillCounter1 + (1/(60*DBTextIndex.Field.Value));
  BillCounterF1:=Format('%1.2f', [BillCounter1]);
  AEdit6.Text:=inttostr(hour)+':'+inttostr(min)+':'+inttostr(sec)+' --- '+BillCounterF1+' dollars ';
end;
```

In the stopwatch, as you can see, there is a bill counter that should count money every second.

In my database, I see `BILL`, `START_TIME`, `END_TIME` and `DURATION_TIME` (difference between `START` and `END` time), and they are correctly shown in the database table.

**The problem is the UI part, where, in the `TEdit` field, the stopwatch and bill counter are lagging, and don't show data as it appears in the database.**

Is there anyone that faced this kind of problem? Is there a way to resolve this? What about using threads? Would that reduce the UI lag?

Note: I am using **Embarcadero Delphi XE7 Architect Edition** with an **MS Access** database.

Comment: A timer will never be as accurate as you would need it to be for your approach. (After all Windows is not a real time operating system...) Why not use the start time of whatever your tracking there and display the running time as `FormatDateTime('hh:nn:ss',now-StartTimeValue)`

Comment: Maybe you didn't understand me, @ub_coding. I need a stopwatch functionality, that starts from 0:0:0 and counts every second. START time and END time are just from the database, and are not related to the stopwatch frontend functionality.

Comment: @user14461368 As ub mentioned, `TTimer` is not real-time, so there could be some lag/drift, which is why it is not good for tracking time accurately.  ub is suggesting is that you can save the starting date/time, such as from `Now()`, at the start of the stopwatch, and then subtract that value from the current date/time from `Now()` on each timer event. That will give you a more accurate duration between each timer event.  Do note that this approach is subject to clock changes, though.  Either from the user, the OS (network time syncs, etc), DST changes, ...

Comment: @user14461368 That being said, Delphi has an actual [`TStopWatch`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Diagnostics.TStopwatch) class. I would suggest using that to track the actual duration, and just use the `TTimer` to update the UI with whatever duration the `TStopWatch` currently reports on each event. `TStopWatch` is more accurate than `TTimer`, as it is not dependent on changes to the OS clock.

Comment: @ub_coding, your suggestion solved my problem. I have inserted another TEdit that shows Now time, and I am subtracting it from Start time to get a stopwatch functionality. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

UI timers are not guaranteed to fire at exactly the specified period. It is normal and expected that they fire somewhat after they have expired.

Instead you should keep track of the time by other means. For instance the system clock, or in your case it seems that `TStopwatch` seems the most accurate. Fire your timer at a higher frequency than you do currently, and check your stopwatch to see if the UI needs updating.